# If I knew what was going on here, I wouldn't ask. Error given is: InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII

Tags: scala, encryption

Ok, so basically, if I am in the console (Intellij) and I type FileScramble.getRandomPW, I get an ASCII password. But if I run the command in the code, I don't. Instead, I get "org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException: InvalidKeySpecException: Password is not ASCII."

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoZHy.jpg) is a screen shot of what I mean.

The fact that I've been up and down that block of code so many times leads me to believe that I'm missing something fundamental in the scala language. The try-catch of the getRandomPW block is never triggered. And, like I said, if I call it from the console, I get only ASCII.

The program is just going to scramble the contents of a file before deletion. It's by no means secure -- it's an exercise. It's me getting familiar with 1) scala, 2) encryption, and 3) sbt.

So here is the relevant code:

```
    import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, File, FileOutputStream, InputStream}
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer
    import java.security.SecureRandom
    import org.jasypt.util.binary.BasicBinaryEncryptor


    object FileScramble {
      val base64chars = ('a' to 'z').union('A' to 'Z').union(0 to 9).union(List('/', '+'))

      def byteArrayToBase64(x: java.nio.ByteBuffer) : String = {
        // convert to string and filter out anything but base64chars
        val nowString = new String(x.array.takeWhile(_ != 0), "UTF-8")
        nowString.filter(base64chars.contains(_))
      } 

      def writeBytes( data : Stream[Byte], file : File ) = {
        val target = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file) );
        try data.foreach( target.write(_) ) finally target.close;
      }

      def getRandomPW : String = {
        try {
          var output : String = ""

          while (output.length() < 10) {
            // val r = scala.util.Random
            val r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG")
            var bytePW : Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](1000)
            r.nextBytes(bytePW)

            // get 1000 random bytes into a ByteBuffer
            val preString = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000).put(bytePW)

            // get a random base 64 password at least 10 chars long
            output = byteArrayToBase64(preString)
          }
          output
        }
        catch {
          case e : Exception => e.getMessage()
        }
      }

      def main( args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
        val fileHandle = new java.io.File(args(0))

        // https://github.com/liufengyun/scala-bug
        val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileHandle, "ISO-8859-1")
        // source = new MyInputStream(dataStream)
        val byteArray = source.map(_.toByte).toArray
        // val byteStream = source.map(_.toByte).toStream

        source.close()

        var binaryEncryptor = new BasicBinaryEncryptor();
        val pw = getRandomPW
        println("BEGIN: " + pw + ":END")
        binaryEncryptor.setPassword(pw);
        val encryptedOut = binaryEncryptor.encrypt(byteArray).toStream
        writeBytes(encryptedOut, fileHandle) 
      }
    }
```

Honestly, I've been up and down the block for a few hours and have not come up with any ideas as to what could be happening. It's by far the biggest head-scratcher I've had recently, to the point that I've asked SO a question for the first time in several years.

Your help is appreciated! I thank you in advance, whether you can help or not.

Comment: You should add the necessary imports / dependencies - specifically, where does `BasicBinaryEncryptor` come from?

Comment: @TzachZohar Thanks, see edit.

Comment: I wrote the answer but voting to close this nonetheless - this is a "why isn't this code working" question, which is considered off topic.

Comment: @TzachZohar Sure, I know SO. Everything's off-topic. It reminds me of reddit, "Come and join us!! ... Now go away!" Thanks for your answer -- I'm testing it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one small, elusive mistake - when you're trying to add the numeric characters 0 - 9, you should add `union('0' to '9')`, instead of `union(0 to 9)` - otherwise you're adding non-ASCII characters (unicode values 0 - 9...) and thus getting the (justifiable) exception.

Comment: The other answer is also right, except that Bob Gleason points to TZ's answer, which is this one. Thank you both. I don't pretend to understand SO's rules, but from a guy that was stuck and is now on the move -- THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

@TzachZohar has it exactly right.

What you might also consider, though, is letting the compiler help you out a bit more by adding your expected type.

```
val base64anys: Seq[Char] = ('a' to 'z').union('A' to 'Z').union(0 to 9).union(List('/', '+'))
```

does not compile. So you would have seen the error.

Comment: Even better is always use `-Ywarn-infer-any` to catch the mistake.